# Add 3 colums and get the MAX value of that addition

Tags: mysql, sql, addition, max, multiple-columns

I have a table and I want to select the value of 3 columns, add this 3 values for each row in the table and get the max value of that sum.

I have tried to the the sum of each row, but its not working, with next sentence I am getting the sum of just 1 row, don't now why it doesn't shows me the rest of the rows.

```
select id, l, rl, cl, sum(l+r+c) as total from pin
```

Comment: I just discover how to get that total.
select id, l, r, c, l+r+c as total from pin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, 
       l, 
       rl, 
       cl, 
       l+r+c as total
       (select max(l+r+c) from pin) as max
from pin
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f480/2)

Comment: `SELECT MAX(l+r+c) as total FROM pin`

   
Is this the same?

Comment: The same as what? My query will give you the fields, the sum of the fields and the max sum of all fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
select *, l+rl+cl as total from pin
```

Here's the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a22b4/5

If you just want the max, you can do this:

```
select max(l+rl+cl) from pin
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a22b4/13